# Django "ImproperlyConfigured", but not always

Tags: python, django

I'm starting a new Django project, using Pycharm 4. I have defined the various models, and if I run tests, such as this,

```
from django.test import TestCase
from models import OwnerDatabase

class TestZero(TestCase):
    def test_Settings(self):
        item=OwnerDatabase.objects.first
```

everything works. But in a different part of the project, if I have this code (a standalone script)

```
from models import OwnerDatabase
```

the program balks with the following traceback

```
  File "/home/piffy/PycharmProjects/Russeau/russeau/datasetcreate.py", line 9, in <module>
    from russeau.models import OwnerDatabase, PublishedDatabase
  File "/home/piffy/PycharmProjects/Russeau/russeau/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class OwnerDatabase(models.Model):
  File "/home/piffy/PycharmProjects/Russeau/russeau/models.py", line 5, in OwnerDatabase
    time = models.DateTimeField()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1098, in __init__
    super(DateField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

But, in manage.py I already have

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Russeau.settings")
```

Though I'm relatively new to Django and Python, my other projects had not such problems. I'm also at a loss as to how to go on.

Thanks!

--- Updated:

Thanks to Daniel, below, I added

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Russeau.settings")
```

So the error now changed to

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

On the good track, but..?

Comment: How are you running datasetcreate.py? It seems like you're invoking it as a standalone script, is that right?

Comment: Yes. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, clearly if you're not running via ./manage.py then setting things there won't help you.

Comment: So, how do I get around it? It is supposed to be a setup script. I'd like to use it within Pycharm, in order to have all of its nice features.

Comment: Why don't you put that `os.environ.setdefault` in your script? Or a better solution is usually to write a [custom manage.py command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/), but I don't know how that would work with Pycharm.

Comment: Lol, the question was answered in the comments while I was writing one. @Daniel wanna write it so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a standalone script, you need to setup Django settings first. In this case, `manage.py` has nothing to do with it because you are not using it to call your script. To fix this, you have two options:

1. Write this at the top of your script:

   ```
   sys.path.append("/path/to/project") #Set it to the root of your project
   os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "<project>.settings"
   django.setup()
   ```

   After that, you should be able to import your models or whatever you need from your project. You can check [this](http://django.zone/posts/importing-django-models-python-script) for more detailed explanation if you want.
2. Create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) so you will be able to call `python manage.py mycommand`.

Comment: I used this variant but it's more or less the same as your proposal. Thanks you all

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Russeau.settings")
import django
django.setup(