# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Visual Studio Code Terminal Error

Tags: python, django

Based on other posts, I've added a new .env file within my app but this error is still appearing. I've also added the top setting module in my settings.py file but still no luck. Any thoughts on what's causing this?

Path to project (where db and manage.py exist): C:\Users\xxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite

Visual Studio Code Terminal Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/xxxx/Python/Price Tracking/Django/mysite/polls/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
PS C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite>
```

error 2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/xxx/Python/Price Tracking/Django/mysite/mysite/settings.py", line 19, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite\mysite\settings.py", line 19, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

settings

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\xxxx\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"
import django
django.setup()
from django.core.management import call_command

from pathlib import Path

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '**=6fb4%z!pxp*ce8$kvj+z2%98)jo&hv!*3*m^wxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'chartjs',
]
```

C:\Users\xxxx\Django\mysite.env file:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='mysite.settings'
```

Comment: Seems like that one helps your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828019/django-improperlyconfigured-but-not-always

Comment: No luck here... I followed these steps and am now getting an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'. I've updated the above code though

Comment: I can't quite understand all of your project schema. So how about you try this now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043853/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysite

Comment: For whatever reason, there are now two mysite folders embedded so I adjusted the code to have a mysite at the end and that portion is now working.... The next error it throws is django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. even though I have a secret key listed in my settings file (see above)

Comment: I don't know why are you getting so many errors one after another. Did all this start to pop up out of nowhere or did you do some recent changes. Maybe the solution is something a lot easier. If you can't figure out, check that as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128540/django-improperlyconfigured-the-secret-key-setting-must-not-be-empty

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines at the top of the script, and the order matters.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

import django
django.setup()

from django.core.management import call_command
```

[For more detail click here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set)

Comment: this is yielding the error: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty. But I do have a secret key listed in my settings.py

Comment: @RCarmody tell me your whole error or put in this question.